# Remove attribute values from product variation title and show them on separate rows

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I have a checkout page where I want to:

- Remove selected product attribute values from product variation title item.
- Remove the quantity from item title too.
- Display the different product attribute value such as size, color and the quantity on different rows, for this product variation item.

I want to display on my checkout page:

> **Aria Sport Shorts** *(the product title)*
>
> **Color:** Dusty Pink
>
> **Size:** Small
>
> **QTY:** 1

Instead of this:

[image: How it looks now]

Is it possible? Where I should start to make this real?

Comment: Please add your codes !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATED**

1) Since WooCommerce 3+, to remove attribute values from Product variation title and to display them in a separate row will need to use this 2 dedicated simple hooks (in checkout page).

- Removing attribute values from Product variation title:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'variation_title_not_include_attributes' );
function variation_title_not_include_attributes( $boolean ){
    if ( ! is_cart() )
        $boolean = false;
    return $boolean;
}
```

- Display Product variation attributes label and values in separate rows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', 'remove_attribute_in_product_name' );
function remove_attribute_in_product_name( $boolean){
    if ( ! is_cart() )
        $boolean = false;
    return $boolean;
}
```

2) Checkout page - Remove the quantity from the product title and add it back in a separate row.

- Remove the quantity from the product title:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'remove_product_variation_qty_from_title', 10, 3 );
function remove_product_variation_qty_from_title( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    if ( $cart_item['data']->is_type('variation') && is_checkout() )
        $quantity_html = '';

    return $quantity_html;
}
```

- Add back the cart item quantity in a separate row:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'filter_get_item_data', 10, 2 );
function filter_get_item_data( $item_data, $cart_item ) {

    if ( $cart_item['data']->is_type('variation') && is_checkout() )
        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'      => __('QTY'),
            'display'  => $cart_item['quantity']
        );

    return $item_data;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested in Woocommerce version 3+ and works. *You should maybe need to make some styling changes…*

Comment: Thanks! I almost get it to work. But when i use the Remove the quantity from the product title i get a fatal error... All other snippets work. 

I guess there is some CSS to get it right to the product thumbnail picture?