# How to remove attributes from product title in woocomerce order view page?

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have attributes which is displayed with product name at the order details pages in frontend and also in backend. How to remove this attributes associated with product name in woocomerce

```
Product name - MATERIAL THICKNESS: 7.5 MIL - CAPITAL LETTER HEIGHT: 2" - SET OPTIONS: LOWERCASE ONLY - CUSTOM_tt: ARRAY × 1
```

Comment: you can use str_replace()

Comment: @gopi This one is also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377644/remove-attribute-values-from-product-variation-title-and-show-them-on-separate-r/47380351#47380351