# Change Woocommerce product quantity in checkout table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, product-quantity

I would like to change the way Woocommerce is displaying the product quantity in the order review table. I would like the quantity to be underneath the product name instead of after it.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377644/remove-attribute-values-from-product-variation-title-and-show-them-on-separate-r) which helped, but the code only changes the quantity layout for variable products.

How can I change it for EVERY product, even simple ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in multiple ways:

1) Overriding [template `checkout/review-order.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.2/templates/checkout/review-order.php) [via your child theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

2) Customizing the product item name:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'customizing_checkout_item_name', 10, 3);
function customizing_checkout_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( is_checkout() )
        $item_name .= '<br>';

    return $item_name;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

3) Customizing the product item quantity *(the **best way**)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'customizing_checkout_item_quantity', 10, 3);
function customizing_checkout_item_quantity( $quantity_html, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    $quantity_html = ' <br>
            <span class="product-quantity">' . __('Quantity:') . ' <strong>' . $cart_item['quantity'] . '</strong></span>';

    return $quantity_html;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).*

All code is tested and works.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is awesome! May I ask you one more thing(I am not sure if I am supposed to start a new question): In the post I linked above you also provided the code to remove the attribute from the product tile and display it underneath. Is it possible to simply just remove the attributes from the title, but NOT display them underneath? I am using "weight" as attributes, and I do have single products that don't have attributes so the simple products would not have a weight displayed underneath which is confusing to the customer...so I#d prfer not to have the attribute shown at all.

Comment: Thanks Loic. I tried the first method which works for me. I think override the template php file is the best way. As the original file says: This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/review-order.php.

Comment: Is there any way to display the quantity  only if its higher than 1?